# Laptop wont' boot up after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

My laptop runs Windows 7 and I install Ubuntu 13.10 on my usb drive.
And my boot loader is on usb drive.

But after I update to Ubuntu 14.04, I can't boot to Windows, it said

```
'error : no such device a517b4990b4d04340eac30-343-434
Entering rescue mode ...
grub rescue>
```

How can I fix this? I think the upgrade process mess up my laptop Windows 7 boot loader.

And when I try to boot to Ubuntu (when my usb drive is connected), I get this error

```
Error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found.
Entering rescue mode....
grub rescue>
```

Now my laptop is not useable since both bootloader is messed up.

Thank you.

I tried this :
http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/492285-Unable-to-boot-after-upgrading-to-13-1-grub_term_highlight_color-not-found

But it said 'grub2-install ' and 'pwd' Unknown command.

Comment: Did you change the boot order in the BIOS?

Comment: No. I did not change anything in BIOS after I upgrade to ubuntu 14.04. It was working. My Windows7 installation (on laptop) works along side with my ubuntu 13.10 (on usb drive). After the upgrade, i can't boot to either environment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not Worry that is quite normal when you put ubuntu alongside Windows.
2nd You need Dual Boot.
When booting into ubuntu run gparted and correct the boot flag.
Also System Monitor shows Resources Allocated
Hope that helps
Uncle Sam

Comment: Just changing the boot flag won't work; it should be on the same partiton. Running Boot Repair should fix it.

Comment: How to run boot repair? I can't boot to either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 14.04